# Using a single helper function as SerializerMethodField in multiple Serializers

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a helper function that gives me the name of the vendor

```
def get_vendor_name(self, obj):
        return (
            obj.affiliate_organisation.current_vendor_version.name
            if obj.affiliate_organisation
            and obj.affiliate_organisation.current_vendor_version
            else None
        )
```

The function will be used by multiple serializers as SerializerMethodField. Is there a better way to define the function once instead of copy pasting it in every serializer separately and resuing the same code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a vendorNameField serializer like this

```
class VendorNameField(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return (
            obj.affiliate_organisation.current_vendor_version.name
            if obj.affiliate_organisation
            and obj.affiliate_organisation.current_vendor_version
            else None
        )
```

this call this serializer filed in other serializers like this

```
class OtherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vendor_name = VendorNameField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourVendorModel
        fields = [
            ...
            'vendor_name',
            ..
        ]
```

NB: assuming your `YourVendorModel` has affiliate_organisation field in it.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is what I was looking for. Out of curiosity where can I learn these tricks and quips. Couldn’t seem to find anything good online.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you, mark this answer as accepted since it worked. actually these are not any tricks, you just read the Django documentation, for better understanding read the source code, then you could solve also solve this.